# Julia: communication between two processes in if-else

Tags: while-loop, task, julia

I have a while loop, where inside of it, two interrelated processes occur. I wanted to let these two processes(one in `if`, the other in `else`) communicate. To better understand the problem, here is the situation:

```
count_if = 0; count_else = 0;
x_if =Vector{Float64}()
x_else = Vector{Float64}()
threshold=.5
while true
    x = rand()
    if x > threshold
        push!(x_if,x)
        count_if +=1
        ###IMPLICIT PART
        ##if count_if = 10, skip this `if`
    else
        push!(x_else,x)
        count_else +=1
        ###IMPLICIT PART
        ###if count_else = 10, skip this `else`
    end
    ###IMPLICIT PART
    ## if both skipped break out of `while`
end
```

So in a way, I want to make sure that if either of the `x_if` or `x_else` reached the limit length of 10, I do not want to add to them. And break rule for the while be when both processes are finished(i.e reached limit length of 10).

Of course I can implement this with separate loops, or set some other if conditions, but I was wondering if I can do this with one run of the loop. I also thought about using something similar to the producer/consumer as explained in the docs, but I was not able to figure it out.

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with communicating processes, but for the given example you can put multiple conditions on the entry, `if x > threshold && count_if != 10`. And make the `else` into `elseif`.

Comment: I mentioned this:`Of course I can implement this with separate loops, or set some other if conditions...`

Comment: There isn't any "implicit condition inside if". There are only entry conditions. I suppose you could yield out and re-check a global value that might have been modified by another task, but that seems excessively complicated.